# нужно в методе add создать бинарное дерево (без использования коллекций) нужно использовать ссылки класса Entry, вообще не понимаю как это сделать?

Tags: java

```
public class CustomTree extends AbstractList <String>implements Cloneable, Serializable {
    Entry<String> root;
    public CustomTree() {
        this.root = new Entry<>("0");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(String s) {

  }   

  static class Entry<T> implements Serializable{
        String elementName;
        boolean availableToAddLeftChildren, availableToAddRightChildren;

        Entry<T> parent, leftChild, rightChild;

        public Entry(String elementName) {
            this.elementName = elementName;
            this.availableToAddLeftChildren = true;
            this.availableToAddRightChildren = true;
        }

        public boolean isAvailableToAddChildren(){
            return availableToAddLeftChildren||availableToAddRightChildren;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на самом деле это не так сложно. делаем упрощенный двусвязный список. нам придется добавить метод get и foreach, чтобы иметь доступ к тому, что положим в наш самодельный двусвязный список. выглядит это примерно так:

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class CustomTree <E> extends AbstractList<E> {

    private int size = 0;

    private Entry<E> first;

    private Entry<E> last;

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        Entry entry;
        //first element in collection        
        if (first == null) {
            entry = new Entry(null, e, null);
            first = entry;
        } 
        else {
            entry = new Entry(last, e, null);
            last.next = entry;
        }
        last = entry;
        size++;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void forEach(Consumer action) {        
        Entry<E> entry = first;
        do{
            action.accept(entry.item);
            entry = entry.next;
        }while (entry!=null);
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        if (index<0 || index>=size) throw new RuntimeException("Out of range");
        Entry<E> entry = first;
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) entry = entry.next;
        return entry.item;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    private static class Entry<E> {
        E item;
        Entry<E> next;
        Entry<E> prev;

        Entry(Entry<E> prev, E element, Entry<E> next) {
            this.item = element;
            this.next = next;
            this.prev = prev;
        }
    }

}
```

ну и метод для того, чтобы продемонстрировать работу:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    CustomTree<Integer> customTree = new CustomTree<>();
    customTree.add(1);
    customTree.add(2);
    customTree.add(3);
    customTree.add(4);

    customTree.forEach(System.out::println);

    System.out.println("**********************************************");

    System.out.println(customTree.get(0));
    System.out.println(customTree.get(1));
    System.out.println(customTree.get(2));
    System.out.println(customTree.get(3));
}
```